ROS 2 topic / node doesn't communicate between two machine in the same network
I attempted the demo of the talker/listener setup using two computers connected on the same network. Initially, I assumed the information would be publicly accessible within the network, but unfortunately, we didn't receive the listener's output on the second PC.(ROS 2)
I attempted to configure the ROS_DOMAIN_ID, ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER, firewall settings (enabled and disabled), and tried using two different networks with various machines (including a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu, two separate computers, Ethernet, and Wi-Fi connections). Despite these efforts, none of the configurations seemed to work.

Solution:
Disable the firewall using the follow command:
sudo ufw disable 

Don’t forget to enable it after finishing your task.
Set the Localhost_only = 0 everytime you open a terminal (or in the bash.rc):
export ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY = 0

